# SQL insert unix timestamp with milliseconds

Tags: date, sql-server-2008-r2

Can unix timestamps contain the milliseconds value of the time?

If so, using SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table_calls_log]
(
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [requestdate] [bigint] NULL,
    [partycode] [bigint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_my_table_calls_log] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

The following select gives me the current date and time with milliseconds:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,SYSDATETIME(),121);
```

Example:

```
2015-09-11 13:29:02.8239061
```

How do I convert that long YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MS date/time value into a unix timestamp so that I can insert it using something like:

```
DECLARE @UnixDate AS bigint;

SET @UnixDate = "the unix timestamp equivalent of SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,SYSDATETIME(),121);"

INSERT INTO my_table_calls_log (requestdate,partycode)
VALUES (@UnixDate,123);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard unix timestamps are 32-bit signed integers with a precision of 1 second (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number)), that said there is certainly nothing invalid about using a 64-bit integer and using a precision of milliseconds if you so choose (so long as you are certain that all code that will use/consume that timestamp value is aware of that constraint). Most standard unix timestamp libraries assume it is a 1 second precision, and if you pass a 64-bit signed integer instead of a 32-bit integer that still holds and the assumption is the user is just planning for a longer life of the timestamp (i.e. to track date/time values past January 19, 2038, which is the date a 32-bit based unix timestamp will stop working at some point from the default epoch due to an overflow).

Unix timestamps also generally assume a base epoch of '1970-01-01 00:00:00', so using that assumption you can convert a standard SQL Server datetime value to a unixtimestamp using something like this:

```
select datediff(second, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', sysdatetime());
```

If you want that to be millisecond based, it becomes a bit more complex as the datediff function in SQL Server is 32-bit integer based (i.e. an int data type) and the difference between the default epoch and the current date/time in milliseconds exceeds the upper-bound of that type, so we have to get a little creative, here is one option (which I tend to use wrapped in a function):

```
declare @start datetime2 = '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000',
        @end datetime2 = sysdatetime(),
        @ms_in_day bigint = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;

select  (@ms_in_day * datediff(day, @start, @end)) - datediff(millisecond, @end, cast(@end as date));
```

In each of these examples, if you have a varchar/character based date/time value, simply insert directly into the script in place of the sysdatetime() function I used.